# Adding subnodes to layermanager?

Tags: boundless-suite

I’m creating an application using OpenGeo Suite SDK and I need to create a two level layer manager. I can create the first layer tree with the "gxp_layermanager" using the following code in the suite-sdk:

```
{
    ptype: "gxp_layermanager",
    groups: {
        "default": "Capas", 
        "MGN":{ 
            title:"Marco Geoestadístico Nacional"
            },
        "TelCom":{ 
            title:"Vías de comunicación"
            },
        "background": { 
            title: "Mapa base", 
            exclusive: true
        }
    },
    outputConfig: {
        id: "tree",
        border: true,
        tbar: [] 
        },
    outputTarget: "westpanel"
},
```

That will put the layers in groups but what I need is to create subgroups or children nodes, pretty much like the left panel [here](http://www.conabio.gob.mx/informacion/gis/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by the framework, you will need to write your own plugin to handle this. See the following code for an example:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/Tridex/blob/master/app/static/script/app/Tridex/NestedLayerTree.js

and here for an example of the config to use:

[https://github.com/boundlessgeo/Tridex/blob/master/app/skins/government.html#L4:L22](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/Tridex/blob/master/app/skins/government.html#L4%3aL22)